# How to determine why a question was closed from the data dump/data explorer

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer, close-reasons

[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) for PostHistory says:

> Comment: This field will contain the comment made by the user who edited a post.
> If PostHistoryTypeId = 10, this field contains the CloseReasonId
> of the close reason:
> 1: Exact Duplicate
> 2: Off-topic
> 3: Subjective and argumentative
> 4: Not a real question
> 7: Too localized
> 10: General reference
> 20: Noise or pointless (Meta sites only)

With the new close reasons, these are site specific ones in the 100+ range.

For the *most* part, reason 102 on Programmers.SE appears to be the 'recommend a tool' close reason.  However, this does not appear to be consistent.

The following query: [Selection of questions with confusing comment / close reason](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/143021/selection-of-questions-with-confusing-comment-close-reason) is, well, confusing.  I've selected a few questions that were closed recently (to avoid any possible problems with changing close reasons of June/July).

The SQL of the query is:

```sql
select
  q.id as [Post Link],
  q.closeddate,
  ph.comment
from
  posts q
  join posthistory ph on (q.id = ph.postid)
where
  ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 10
  and ph.comment = 102
  and q.id in (213960, 213983, 140658, 214117, 10920)
```

The results are:

```
id     closeddate          comment 
------ ------------------- ------- 
10920  2013-10-11 17:16:47 102     
140658 2013-10-11 07:58:04 102     
214117 2013-10-11 07:53:30 102     
213983 2013-10-11 21:56:31 102     
213960 2013-10-12 13:53:56 102
```

Of these:

- [10920](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10920/how-to-choose-a-research-discipline-in-computer-science) - career or education advice.
- [140657](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140658/what-language-or-tool-will-allow-me-to-manipulate-60-000-words-in-a-text-file) - recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource.
- [214117](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/214117/is-there-a-command-to-make-running-fullscreen-app-go-into-windowed-mode-and-how) - custom reason.
- [213983](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213983/dummy-data-to-work-with-google-map) - recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource.
- [213960](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/213960/is-it-legal-to-distribute-exes-inside-system32-folder-with-my-product) - custom reason.

Am I misreading/using the comment field? Is there some documentation missing on what it means? Is there some glitch/bug in loading the data into Data.SE?

Or at its *real* core, how do I get all the questions that were closed for "recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource" and *only* the questions that were closed for that reason?  Is the data wrong? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Pending close votes *are* present in the database, but not those same votes after closure has completed. Grmbl.

Answer (score 6):

> For the most part, reason 102 on Programmers.SE appears to be the 'recommend a tool' close reason.

No, reason 102 is any reason of the "off-topic" category. See the query [Show all types](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/36599/show-all-types).

The reason "recommend a tool" is off-topic reason listed with `Id=8` in the table  CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes. The problem is that this Id number can't be matched to anything because the **OffTopicReasonType is not in the PostHistory table**. It logically belongs to the Text column of that table, which contains all of the other information in the closure notice: the list of those who voted to close, and (for duplicates) the original question and whether the dupehammer was used.

Or perhaps OffTopicReasonType  can be given a column of its own, alongside the existing "Comment" column, which contains the category of closure reason.

Is this a bug or missing feature? I can't tell.

Comment: The feature request to split off-topic reasons is at [Please add the individual close-as-off-topic reason in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297750/please-add-the-individual-close-as-off-topic-reason-in-the-data-explorer).