# Can someone analyze the Close Vote queue on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close, downloads

Can someone with access to the right data produce some analysis of the Close Vote queue?

When I work out how, or when I can do it, there will be a substantial (for me) Bounty for something effective.

I want what many want: which is how to deal with the Close Queue. Here are some analysis that may be useful:

- An analysis **by age** would be useful.
- Analysis **by tag** would be useful.
- If the "**skip count**" is available, analysis by that (say three broad groups to begin with - what are the "thirds" of the total queue?).
- An analysis of **users by some grouping of rep**, with Moderators another group.
- An analysis of **top users down** (to get an idea of how many users need to be encouraged such that an impact can be expected judged by the ratios of work done by people currently).

As well as lots of other things. Having never even seen the queue myself, it is difficult to be definitive or correct. Feel free to edit in suggestions....

Someone in the comments asked whether offering fries would be an incentive. Don't know where to start with that one.

Some more suggestions based on the comments:

- For each language tag: the ratio of questions in the queue to close-voters with expertise (say, a bronze badge in the tag). SO could recruit more mods from areas in which the ratio is high; and concerned folks could start meta or chat conversations to come up with new norms for questions in those areas. – @Frank
- Perhaps to extend to get some idea of the potential resource available per language tag (if languages themselves can be identified from tags?). How many, broken down by 3k, 10k, 20k have N+ Accepted answers in language tag.
- An analysis of 'active' 3k+ users and how many close votes they cast per day on average (in the last ... month? week? year? and in total) (and similar analyses of users at higher reps, e.g. 10k+, 20k+)  – @Dukeling

This might underpin, or undermine, the idea that the size of the Close Vote queue is demotivating.

- Do reviewers slow down once they've achieved a badge milestone?
- Can the effects of existing robo-voting be quantified?
- Ratio of review tests passed vs review test failures, for 3k, 10k, 20k.
- What is adding to the queue the most? In the last 30 days, how many questions are from the last thirty days, and how many from 60, 90, 180, 360, 720 days?
- How many questions on the queue have (mutually exclusive): Accepted answers; More than one Upvoted answer; One Upvoted answer; More than one answer; One answer; no answers.
- Same answer as previous, but for events which happened since question became Hold/on the Close Vote queue.
- Ratio of questions per tag as a whole vs questions per tag on Close Vote queue.
- On Hold must feed into the Close Votes. Can On Hold movements be analysed for the existing data?

Comment: What kind of analysis do you want? I have pending items by tag (and some variations on that) for an answer I'm working on elsewhere; it's also easy enough for me to break it up by close reason, look at the outcome of already-reviewed items, etc... Just let me know.

Comment: @Shog9: Can you get a count of how many are "tag:C++" AND "reason:Off-topic-must-have-minimal-understanding"? (Or point me to a parametrized query?)

Comment: If you want to try out stuff about when questions do get closed (not about the close queue itself) in the data explorer, see [How to determine why a question was closed from the data dump/data explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202025/how-to-determine-why-a-question-was-closed-from-the-data-dump-data-explorer)

Comment: Do you want fries with that too?

Comment: I could go for some french-fry soup right now...

Comment: You may or may not find this helpful, but [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/106699/get-unclosed-questions-with-closed-votes)'s a query that gets open questions with close votes, sorted by most votes including a clickable link to question (which I made for [another reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167109/close-votes-policy-review)). Feel free to try to make something useful of it.

Comment: The answer to that is 301, @Kerrek

Comment: @Shog9: Neat, thanks - on the one hand, that's a quantity I feel comfortable tackling; on the other hand, it'll make absolutely no difference to the first n decimal places of the queue size :-S

Comment: Not to give too much away (since, as I said, I'm writing another answer on this that goes into much more detail), but... There is a *massively long* tail to the queue. I recommend reviewing to improve your own little corner of the site; SO is too big to drink from the firehose @Kerrek.

Comment: @Shog9 Yet the close vote queue is one giant firehose...

Comment: Not if you filter it, @Dukeling...

Comment: @Dukeling What about filtering by tag?

Comment: You can filter by reason *and* tag, @Dukeling. Try... OT + [tag:regex] and you'll be looking at under 300 (unfortunately, you can't do AND tag combos, so you can't further reducing this by adding [tag:java]).

Comment: I'd want to see, for each language tag: the ratio of questions in the queue to close-voters with expertise (say, a bronze badge in the tag). SO could recruit more mods from areas in which the ratio is high; and concerned folks could start meta or chat conversations to come up with new norms for questions in those areas.

Comment: @Shog9 Oh right. Forgot about that. Though I'd like to see this functionality extended (maybe to a UI similar to the questions) - last time I tried, filtering only made it worse because I can't ignore tags.

Comment: I didn't think through the Bounty thing. Perhaps multiple ones (is that possible?). @Dukeling can those results from your queries be updated? The count one gives a better guess at how many activities may remain to get the whole queue closed. rather than just 85k by some number.

Comment: @BillWoodger If you mean the numbers look a little low - I have no idea why. I more meant for the query to be used as a starting point to extract any desired statistics. Random observation - I do find it kind of curious that `# 1 vote q's + 2*# of 2 vote q's + 3*# of 3 vote q's` ≈ 84k = # displayed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review) (keeping in mind that the last update to the data was 1/2 a month ago, which could account for the `# of 4 vote q's`).

Comment: The answer you want is 42

Comment: @Dukeling Have you just cut the queue by 30,000 "questions" with that then? 55,000 **questions** on the queue with ~84k **votes**? I like "(maybe a little off)". Maybe a lot off and a big stride forward :=) Any confirmation...? Anyone? Has the wording on the Review page been wrong all this time? 55k is still a lot, but a lot less.

Comment: I'm not sure about the current last item (my fault). I thought the timings requested earlier would get confused with the On Hold. It was late, and I started making things up about On Hold. I attempted an edit, snafu'd it and decided to go to bed rather than mess it up more :-) The last is probably meaningless as it is, but with the new On Hold working, it probably means it is old stuff creating the backlog, but why speculate if there will be info coming :-)

Comment: Perhaps it would also be nice to have a Tag for the Close Vote Queue Issue. Keep everything tied together? I probably know it should be another question, but fearful of being fried again. At least if a comment goes down badly I can just bin it :-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163830/how-slow-is-the-close-votes-queue-being-processed-and-how-large-should-it-get-d. And I got the "fries" response too.

Comment: @BillWoodger You can put multiple bounties on a question sequentially, but each bounty has to be double the last. See _"Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired?"_ in [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/152515)