# How can we write a query in data.stackexchange to find the CloseAsOffTopicReasonType for a closed question?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am attempting some data mining via `data.stackexchange` but failing in my current task, as I cannot find the "off topic reason" for closed "off-topic" questions.

Given a closed 'off topic' question such as my randomly chosen victim question, 17335689:

[question 17335689](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335689/good-jquery-plugin-for-image-zoom-in-an-absolute-position-div-to-the-side-like)

We can see from visiting the question that its "Off-Topic Reason" is:

> questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource** are off-topic

...but how can we craft a query in Data.Stackexchange that unearths this fact? 
(i.e. that returns the `CloseAsOffTopicReasonType` for a **closed** question)

I've tried by writing a series of queries here:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/309888/looking-for-off-topic-close-reason-details

None of the many queries contained at that link unearthed the "Off topic reason" for that question.

There is a "pending flags" table that points back to `Posts`. But there are no pending flags for this closed question.

(I am now certain that `PendingFlags` only exist when a question is not yet closed.)

I've included step by step breakdown of what I've tried so far in [the comments of the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/309888/looking-for-off-topic-close-reason-details)

I looked in the following tables:

- Posts
- PostHistory
- PendingFlags
- Comments
- Votes
- ReviewTasks
- ReviewTaskResults

None of them contained the data that clearly does exist.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202025/how-to-determine-why-a-question-was-closed-from-the-data-dump-data-explorer

Comment: Notice that the sub-close-reason is also not available from the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=17335689&filter=!--pn9shfFyzy&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: Thanks Rene, if you create an answer from your comment(s) I am happy to award you the bounty and call off the search for off-topic sub reasons. Thanks muchly! lb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write such a query at the moment because that data is not in any tables of the current schema in SEDE. The same conclusion was reached by [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/yes) in an answer on [How to determine why a question was closed from the data dump/data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202025/how-to-determine-why-a-question-was-closed-from-the-data-dump-data-explorer)

The other option might be the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). The endpoint for a specific [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=17335689&filter=!iCF4LsD_mMhZBltpQytgHH&site=stackoverflow&run=true) doesn't output the off-topic sub close reason in a field, but ....

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "closed_details": {
                "description": "This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason: <ul class=\"close-as-off-topic-status-list\">\r\n        <li>&quot;Questions asking us to <b>recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource</b> are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, <a href=\"http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/\">describe the problem</a> and what has been done so far to solve it.&quot; &ndash; Juhana, Toto, ThiefMaster</li>\r\n    </ul>",
                "reason": "off-topic"
            },
            "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335689/good-jquery-plugin-for-image-zoom-in-an-absolute-position-div-to-the-side-like",
            "title": "Good jQuery plugin for image zoom in an absolute position div to the side? (like ecommerce sites)"
        }
    ]
}
```

...as you can see the exact reason is in the description of the [closed_details type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/closed-details). You can parse that to get the sub-close reason. The downside though of the API is that only 10000 calls per day are allowed and requests are throttled per IP-address so you won't be able to analyze/parse large sets.

Comment: That's perfect. Parsing the closed_details is not only suitable, but exactly the sort of thing I enjoy. The 10,000 calls per day limit will not be a problem. Excellent.